# Where does ClipChamp save the audio file created by the TTS feature?

Tags: video-editing, text-to-speech

I use ClipChamp for my personal video editing and, oftentimes, I use its text-to-speech (TTS) feature.
When I create the audio files for the video I'm current editing, it works great.
However, when I need the audio file for a different project, is a hassle. I have to:

- Create a different project,
- Create the TTS file and add to the timeline,
- Export as a scrap video,
- Import that video back into ClipChamp,
- Add that video to the timeline,
- Separate the audio from the video,
- and **only** then I have the TTS file for my separated project.

I searched here, Google, ChatGPT and I wasn't able to find something that should be trivial.

**Where** does ClipChamp saves its TTS files?

Comment: Probably “%LocalAppData%\Packages\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_yxz26nhyzhsrt\”

Comment: @Ramhound I wish it was that simple. But it's not. There are many sub-folder in there, but they are ultimately empty or contains only json files.

Comment: Use an app like Everything with recent date sorting to find out

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing (in 04.Sept.2023) ClipChamp does **NOT** store text-to-sppech files locally.

Apparently it uses Microsoft servers for the TTS feature, and it stores the files there.

So, as this moment, the *ONLY* way to get the audio file is through the steps mentioned in the question.

**NOTE:** I'm writing this answer to document and keep it as reference for other people looking for the same answer.